# .Bat file to unzip files from an .exe file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, zip

I have created an .exe file containing a test.zip file and a extract.bat file.
I am trying to configure the extract.bat file so that it can extract the test.zip to C:\Temp folder.

The bat file looks like this :

```
echo off
setlocal
cd /d %~dp0
Call :UnZipFile "C:\Temp\" **for /F %%I IN ('dir /b /s *.zip)**
exit /b

:UnZipFile <ExtractTo> <newzipfile>
set vbs="%temp%\_.vbs"
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
>%vbs%  echo Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>>%vbs% echo If NOT fso.FolderExists(%1) Then
>>%vbs% echo fso.CreateFolder(%1)
>>%vbs% echo End If
>>%vbs% echo set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
>>%vbs% echo set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace(%2).items
>>%vbs% echo objShell.NameSpace(%1).CopyHere(FilesInZip)
>>%vbs% echo Set fso = Nothing
>>%vbs% echo Set objShell = Nothing
cscript //nologo %vbs%
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
```

I am confused and to be honest not sure if I am doing it correctly.It does not work. My challenge is I am unable to declare the location of the .zip file as both the test.zip file and the extract.bat file would be a part of the same .exe file. Also, I am using Iexpress.exe to create the .exe file.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the extract script is part of the exe file, just make a self-extracting executable which would self-extract itself in a specified location. (This is the object-oriented approach, by the way: you tell the exe archive to unpack itself ;) IExpress is only one of available options.